# What are Virtual Machine Workstations and how do they work?

Tags: windows, vmware, virtual-machine

I heard from our sister company that they are using Windows Virtual Machine workstation. I didn't have a chance to ask them what this means. But I am not sure how this works. Is this scenario possible.

A user has a physical box, and he has Windows OS and he has a Virtual Windows on his box?? Unless he has a Linux OS, why would he want a Virtual Windows on top of a Windows OS.

Anyhow, is someone familiar with the phrase 'Windows Virtual Machine workstation' and how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for having virtual Windows on top of a Windows installation is typically for development, legacy applications, testing and evaluation - amongst other things.

What you are referring to sounds to me like a "VDI" which means [Virtual Desktop Infrastructure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vdi). It is typically where users have a "Dumb terminal" or a very light specification machine and simply remote in to another machine.

Years ago this was done with mainframes, but computers seem to have gone full circle and companies are increasingly buying very high specification servers then virtualising them and offering "Virtual Desktops" where these terminals just remote in to.

The advantages to this is a very low administration cost (Excluding high licensing costs!) as everything is centralised and very easy to manage.

Answer (score 3):

By "Windows Virtual Machine workstation" they could be referring to [VMWare workstation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_Workstation) by the sounds of it, but there's a few products out there for this purpose. [VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org) and [Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/) to name others.

> A user has a physical box, and he has
>   Windows OS and he has a Virtual
>   Windows on his box?? Unless he has a
>   Linux OS, why would he want a Virtual
>   Windows on top of a Windows OS.

Lots of reasons. To name a few:

- Testing newer versions of windows
- Running older versions of windows
- Programming & compatibility checking (which may tie into the above two)
- Sandboxing/Testing program installation
- A safe usage environment for themselves or their family members. If a virus infects the virtual machine it can simply be reverted to an earlier snapshot.